# Inheriting a common base class in php

Tags: php

I am working on an application that has two types of users. I have an abstract base class to provide common functionality to the two user types: Publishers and Consumers. Currently I have a need to display information on a publihser and a consumer on the same page. When I include both the consumer.php and the publisher.php I get the following error:

> ```
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class baseUser ...
> ```

Is it not possible in php to include two classes that happen in inherit the same base class?

Comment: no that is not possible. A class has to be unique

Comment: Are you using `require()` or `require_once()` to get your base class included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `require_once` to ensure that your base class's file is included in your codebase only once.

Comment: Worst case fix, wrap the classdef with an if(class_exists("foo")){ classdef.. }

Comment: @David **No, don't do that**. That's hiding the problem, not fixing it. Use `require_once`. This is specifically the problem it is designed to fix. Do *not* roll your own solution to this problem.

Comment: @meager Like I said worst case

Comment: @David No, *no* case. Don't do this, in *any* case. It's never the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: @Meager I know one case when a group of competent engineers felt that was the only solution.  Specifics I was hired to fix a PHP SaaS application that had about 16GB of auto-generated PHP files and it was not time feasible to extract the classdefs or do anything else.  Knowing the right way is good and prefered but knowing bad alternatives can be useful when dealing with bad software designs.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing is caused by a multiple inclusion of the "baseUser" class definition.

This means that you're including the class file more than once. Make sure that you're using `include_once` or `require_once` instead of regular `include` or `require`.

You can also make your own control mechanisms (using sentinel variables, as you may do in C++) but i recommend to use the method explained above

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), so you won't think about filesystem anymore, but about a real codebase.

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading) does it all for you, following the conventions used by PHP OOP community at the moment.

This way you can focus on real development, and not about `require` statements [we are in 2013 ^^].